# What happened to Xsd2Code class generator Add-in for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-addins, xsd2code

I am using Version 3.4 and it is no longer working and the link on codeplex indicates, "This project is not yet published."  Maybe an exception is thrown in the check for updates because the Generate button is not doing anything.  Anyone know what is up with this utility?

http://xsd2code.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link started working again. Not sure why it was down.  Also, my 3.4 version is working now (was referencing an old workspace).  False alarm.  My bad.